# Math.random() and Math.floor() why are they used together?

Tags: javascript, function

also is it possible that the generated number  be between 30 and 90. or it is just generated between 0 and n?

Comment: What do you mean by "are used together"?

Comment: Title and question do not relate. Also do you know how to add 30?

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a floating point number between 0 and 1. `Math.floor()` will truncate that number (eg: `Math.floor(1.45); // returns 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: The `(max - min + 1)` seems wrong. Shouldn't it just be `(max - min)`?

Answer (score 0):

Generate numbers between 0 and 60 (you seem to know how that works), then add 30.